# Reduce dimensions in RANSAC code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reduce the dimensions in RANSAC code. This is the original code:

```
function [ output_args ] = ransac( filename)

mov = VideoReader(filename);
numFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;

for i=1:numFrames
    file_name = sprintf('frames/%0.3i.jpg', i);
    file_name2 = sprintf('frames/%0.3i.jpg', i+1);

    I1=im2double(imread(file_name2));
    I2=im2double(imread(file_name));

    % Get the Key Points
    Options.upright=true;
    Options.thresh=0.0001;
    Ipts1=OpenSurf(I1,Options);
    Ipts2=OpenSurf(I2,Options);

    % Put the landmark descriptors in a matrix
    D1 = reshape([Ipts1.descriptor],64,[]);
    D2 = reshape([Ipts2.descriptor],64,[]);

    % Find the best matches
    err=zeros(1,length(Ipts1));
    cor1=1:length(Ipts1);
    cor2=zeros(1,length(Ipts1));

    for i=1:length(Ipts1),
        distance=sum((D2-repmat(D1(:,i),[1 length(Ipts2)])).^2,1);
        [err(i),cor2(i)]=min(distance);
    end

    % Sort matches on vector distance
    [err, ind]=sort(err);
    cor1=cor1(ind);
    cor2=cor2(ind);

    % Make vectors with the coordinates of the best matches
    Pos1=[[Ipts1(cor1).y]',[Ipts1(cor1).x]'];
    Pos2=[[Ipts2(cor2).y]',[Ipts2(cor2).x]'];
    Pos1=Pos1(1:30,:);
    Pos2=Pos2(1:30,:);

    % Show both images
    I = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)*2 size(I1,3)]);
    I(:,1:size(I1,2),:)=I1; I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)=I2;

    % Calculate affine matrix
    Pos1(:,3)=1; Pos2(:,3)=1;
    M=Pos1'/Pos2';

    % Add subfunctions to Matlab Search path
    functionname='OpenSurf.m';
    functiondir=which(functionname);
    functiondir=functiondir(1:end-length(functionname));
    addpath([functiondir '/WarpFunctions'])

    % Warp the image
    I1_warped=affine_warp(I1,M,'bicubic');

    % Show the result
    subplot(1,3,1), imshow(I1);title('Figure 1');
    subplot(1,3,2), imshow(I2);title('Figure 2');
    subplot(1,3,3), imshow(I1_warped);title('Warped Figure 1');

    imwrite(I1_warped,file_name2);
    if (mod(i,20) == 0)  
       disp(sprintf('he make a %d',i)); 
    end
end
sprintf('finish');
```

When I change the values in the lines

```
D1 = reshape([Ipts1.descriptor],64,[]);
D2 = reshape([Ipts2.descriptor],64,[]);
```

to:

```
D1 = reshape([Ipts1.descriptor],32,[]);
D2 = reshape([Ipts2.descriptor],32,[]);
```

I get the following error:

> Error using  -
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>   Error in `ransac (line 33)`
>
> `distance=sum((D2-repmat(D1(:,i),[1 length(Ipts2)])).^2,1);`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have changed the dimensions of `D1` and `D2`, this line is no longer valid anymore:

```
distance=sum((D2-repmat(D1(:,i),[1 length(Ipts2)])).^2,1);
```

What's happening in `D1`, `D2` is that it is taking a 1D vector and reshaping it into a matrix that has 64 rows.  I'm assuming that the SURF descriptor has every keypoint represented as a 64 element vector.  You are probably using 32 now because you want to represent each SURF descriptor as 32 bins instead of 64.  If you do this, you would be using **two** columns to represent a single feature where the original code had it as one column per feature.  As such, when doing that distance calculation, it isn't replicating the total number of columns right as when you reshape using 64 rows, the total number of columns **is exactly** the total number of keypoints that were detected from SURF.

What I would recommend that you do is configure your SURF descriptor so that the output for each feature is 32 bins, not 64.  However, if you want to get this statement to work, you need to change the `length` statement to calculate as many columns as there are in `D1` or `D2`.  As such:

```
distance=sum((D2-repmat(D1(:,i),[1 size(D2,2)])).^2,1);
```

---

I don't believe the above statement will correctly determine the distance between features because each column would essentially be half of a feature, and so if you were to find the best matching feature, it would choose the best column... and again, this is only half of a feature.

I would recommend you read up on SURF again, because simply changing the reshaping from 64 to 32 does **not** reduce the dimensionality of your features.

---

## Sidenote

If you want to avoid this matrix dimension error completely, I would personally use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as it would automatically replicate the dimensions for you, without doing `repmat`.  As such, I would personally replace that line of code with:

```
distance = sum(bsxfun(@minus, D2, D1(:,i)).^2, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if its not help me to reduce the dimensions in the code, what should i change in the code to do that?

Comment: @HilaShahar - As I said, of course it won't. You have to configure your SURF descriptor so that it outputs 32-bin vectors rather than 64.  You have to configure this yourself, as I'm not familiar with how to configure OpenSURF.  Suggest you read the documentation or the README on how you do that.